# Selenium - Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: cannot create temp dir for unpacking extensions

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

### Problem

I'm attempting to run Selenium from a Java application (more specifically a Talend job). The job runs fine locally, however, when it's deployed to Windows Server 2019 I'm getting the following error:

> Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: cannot create temp dir for unpacking extensions

Here's my Selenium Java code:

```
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("download.default_directory",  "C:\\data\\");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
options.addArguments("--headless");
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
options.addArguments("--profile-directory=Default");
options.addArguments("--user-data-dir=C:\\Temp");


WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
Map<String, Object> vars = new HashMap<String, Object>();
 
   
driver.get("<URI>");
driver.findElement(By.id("<a valid element id for my case>")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.close();
driver.quit();
```

### Things I've tried

- Setting TMP and TEMP environment variables to C:\Temp
- Setting the chromedriver.exe executable to "Run as Administrator" via the properties dialog of the executable
- Setting the `---user-data-dir` flag to a C:\Temp (as seen above)
- Deleting the Temp directory (both the default and the current C:\Temp I'm trying)
- Verified the drive has plenty of free space
- Restarting the server
- Downgrading chromedriver.exe to Chrome versions 101, 100, and 99
- Changing --user-data-dir to C:\Temp\2
- Setting "Do not delete temp folders upon exit" and "Do not use temporary folders per session" Group Policy Flags to "Enabled"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Root cause of the issue was actually related to the fact that the Java code was being executed as the SYSTEM user instead of a named account. (Specifically, the Talend Remote Engine was being run as SYSTEM). I switched the code to run as a named account which resolved the error.

Answer (score 0):

A 500 error code means that there is a problem with the server. Seeing as you've already tried to restart and check the disk space of the server, the issue might be with the temp directory.

Go to the windows CLI and execute `echo %temp%`:

Some users are getting `C:\TEMP\2` returned. If this (or any other folder name) happens, make the new folder and make sure you are running as admin

Comment: Running that command returns `C:\Temp` which does exist and actually has files in it. There is a C:\Temp\2 folder in there as well.

Comment: try to set the flag to C\\:Temp\2 in the code. Each windows session makes a new temp directory (this can be changed in group policy), and I believe its why its causing the issue

Comment: I changed over the setting to use C:\Temp\2 and tried changing the use of temporary folders settings under the Remote Desktop portion of Group Policy. Anything else to try?

Comment: Unfortunately im not sure what else, usually these solutions have fixed the problem. I apologize but hope it resolves!